# How to get data from Azure Table Storage to SharePoint Online

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-table-storage, sharepoint-online

I need to get data from Azure table storage and populate in SharePoint O365 site as a list. I found a way to achieve if it's from SQL Azure but couldn't able to find for Azure Tables. Kindly share your inputs.

Comment: I think this is an opinion based question

Answer (score 0):

Azure Table and SharePoint both have APIs, so in the base case you can import from one and export to others using their APIs. However, it seems you are looking for a tool, not to write code.

To export from Azure Tables you can use the AzCopy Tool (http://aka.ms/azcopy) to export the contents into a Json-formatted local file. Then, you can use whatever tool you use to import into SharePoint, as long as it understands Json files.

Comment: Thankyou for your response, I could like to have it in-sync. If its a SQL Azure then i can use BCS with Secure Store mapping but for Azure Table is there any way to keep it up-to-date.

Comment: Can you explain more by what you mean when you say "I could like to have it in-sync"? Do you mean that you want something to periodically automatically synchronize Azure Tables with the Sharepoint list? I am not aware of anything that does that.